Tailwind arbitrary properties not being applied at all
I have the following code for developing a login page. For one particular div I'm attempting to use clip-path. Since tailwind doesn't handle clip-path, according to the Tailwind Guidelines, I can still use the styling so long as I close it with brackets. I've done this and it does not work. Below is my code:
import LoginForm from "@/components/ui/login";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="basis-1/3 bg-gradient-to-b from-cp-1/70
                                                   via-cp-2/70
                                                   via-cp-3/70
                                                   via-cp-4/70
                                                   to-cp-5/70" 
                                                   />
            <div class="flex basis-1/4 ">
                <div class="grow border 
                            bg-gradient-to-b from-cp-1/70
                             via-cp-2/70 via-cp-3/70 via-cp-4/70 
                             to-cp-5/70 
                             [clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%)]" 
                             />
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <LoginForm />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

And here's an image for greater context, with the problem div outlined in white.

This solution appears to be a decent workaround, but isn't this just something that should be working?. I must also add that it's not just clip-path, but rather any arbitrary properties I close in brackets don't get recognized. You can view my tailwind.config.js as well. Am I making a CSS mistake or is Tailwind being weird or did I misunderstand the Tailwind instructions? Thanks

No spaces allowed between []

You can't use spaces inside arbitrary properties, since space is a class delimiter. The correct tailwind syntax would be:
className="[clip-path:polygon(0_100%,100%_0,100%_100%)]".

Thanks. I cant believe how much time I spent trying to fix this lol
